# How to keep data secured from access via a public directory on apache server

Tags: apache, security, public

I have to design a website where users with account will upload images. Many users will upload their images and these images need to visible to the owner only in their account.

Normally We have web directory structure like **/httpdocs/images/user1_id/file_name.jpg** and **/httpdocs/images/user2_id/file_name.jpg** but this brings security issue that anyone who knows the public file directory structure can access the complete image directory.

How can I solve this security issue?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to solve this would be to add a hash to the image url.
 Many CMS tackle this problem similarly by obfuscating the URL, where they create a hash (md5) or SHA and append it before the filename like:

```
/httpdocs/images/user1_id/043a718774c572bd8a25adbeb1bfcd5c0256ae11cecf9f9c3f925d0e52beaf89_file_name.jpg
```

Internally, you end up saving the hash+filename instead of only filename in your database.

The next step is to obviously disable the access of the file-listing within [the apache htaccess](http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/prevent-directory-listing-htaccess.shtml).

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look to this [link](https://maze.io/2010/02/09/restricting-directory-in-apache-per-logged-in-user/), which explains a problem very similar to yours.

Example Virtual Host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName docs.maze.io
    DocumentRoot /export/docs
    <Directory /export/docs>
        # No .htaccess allowed
        AllowOverride None

        # Authenticate through LDAP
        AuthType basic
        AuthName "docs area"
        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        AuthLDAPBindDN "userid=apache,dc=maze,dc=io"
        AuthLDAPBindPassword "secret"
        AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://ldap.net.maze.io/dc=maze,dc=io"
        AuthLDAPGroupAttribute memberUid
        AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off
        Require ldap-group cn=docs,ou=Groups,dc=maze,dc=io

        # Enable WebDAV
        DAV On
    </Directory>

    # Restrict /home/* to /home/%{REMOTE_USER} access only
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/home/(?:|README\.x?html?|index\..+)$
    RewriteRule ^.* - [L]
    RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} ^(.+)
    RewriteCond %1:/home/$1 !^([^:]+):/home/\1$
    RewriteRule ^/home/([^/]+) - [F,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution after applying some understanding. This is a two step solution

1. Disable directory browsing(which is by default disabled)
2. Name your files randomly so that one cannot guess the complete path to the file.